# How do you get data attribute of option tag in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, custom-data-attribute

I have got select element with a value already assigned and I have added a data attribute. I can get the value of the element in php and I know how to get the data attribute using JavaScript but I really want to send the values from the data attribute in the form. Is this possible? Thanks in advance for your help. Here is an example of my code:

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="prod_sku">Size:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="prod_sku" name="prod_sku">
                  <option value="sku_GGdBzZqwz443UhRf" data-price="20.00">125 ml</option>
                  <option value="sku_GJ78tLAGYOIiuwjT" data-price="45.00">500 ml</option>
                  <option value="sku_GJ77wDMtvx8n4Mbh" data-price="300.00">5 ltr</option>
             </select>
        </div>
<input id="prod_price" name="prod_price" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['prod_sku -> data-price']; ?>">
```

I need to send the price of the selected sku option to MySQL. The form method is post and the hidden input is inside the form. 
My end goal is to send the sku and its associated price to the database per secection. So if the user selects the first option the sku for that option and the price for that option get sent together.

Comment: php can't work on the client side. If you don't want to use AJAX/ javascript onchange, you need <form></form> and a submit button.

Comment: on change select option, store data attribute value in one hidden input, so you can get in on server side.

Comment: Why would you even need that? Sounds more like a defect of the database design, or processing logic. Why accept a client-side price value, when it could already be inferred from the product id and safely from the db?

Comment: My end goal is to send the sku and its associated price to the database per secection. So if the user selects the first option the sku for that option and the price for that option get sent together.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with change event jQuery and assign it to input. Then you can easily get value to your server-side as a post request.

```js
$('#prod_sku').change(function(){        
  $("#prod_price").val($(this).find(':selected').attr('data-price') + " Rs");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="prod_sku">Size:</label>
     <select class="form-control" id="prod_sku" name="prod_sku">
         <option value="sku_GGdBzZqwz443UhRf" data-price="20.00">125 ml</option>
         <option value="sku_GJ78tLAGYOIiuwjT" data-price="45.00">500 ml</option>
         <option value="sku_GJ77wDMtvx8n4Mbh" data-price="300.00">5 ltr</option>
     </select><br><br>
</div>
<input id="prod_price" name="prod_price" value="">
```